# Unable to inherit and override ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to build a custom ArrayAdapter that overrides the constructor of the default ArrayAdapter like so:

```
private class MyEndpointAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Endpoint> {
```

but I get an error saying:

```
There is no default constructor available in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter'
```

I decided to check the ArrayAdapter's declaration and discovered that some of the classes it imports, cannot be resolved

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tauGr.png

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not provide a constructor explicitly, the compiler will create a default constructor for you, which will call the no-arg constructor of the superclass.

Since `ArrayAdapter` does not have a no-arg constructor, this call obviously cannot be made, hence the error.

You need to define a constructor explicitly that invokes a constructor from the superclass, for example:

```
private class MyEndpointAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Endpoint> {

    public MyEndpointAdapter(Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, List<Endpoint> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }
}
```